# not able to run or build flutter for web showing many errors

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, android-studio, flutter-web

i purchased a code from codecanyon. after reskin it, working good. after some days i'm not able to build apk and web. i already followed all of documentation of them. the code link is [https://codecanyon.net/item/grofresh-grocery-pharmacy-ecommerce-store-app-and-web-with-laravel-admin-panel-delivery-app/32791631](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

i already contacted with support, but they are not helping me. while i'm trying to run web it's showing the below error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart:116:5: Error: Type
'SelectNotificationCallback' not found.
    SelectNotificationCallback? onSelectNotification,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:99:3: Error: Type
'SelectNotificationCallback' not found.
  SelectNotificationCallback? _onSelectNotification;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:110:5: Error: Type
'SelectNotificationCallback' not found.
    SelectNotificationCallback? onSelectNotification,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:472:3: Error: Type
'SelectNotificationCallback' not found.
  SelectNotificationCallback? _onSelectNotification;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:494:5: Error: Type
'SelectNotificationCallback' not found.
    SelectNotificationCallback? onSelectNotification,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:702:3: Error: Type
'SelectNotificationCallback' not found.
  SelectNotificationCallback? _onSelectNotification;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:725:5: Error: Type
'SelectNotificationCallback' not found.
    SelectNotificationCallback? onSelectNotification,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications_linux-0.3.1-dev.1/lib/src/flutter_local_notifications_stub.dart:26:5: Error: Type
'SelectNotificationCallback' not found.
    SelectNotificationCallback? onSelectNotification,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications_linux-0.3.1-dev.1/lib/src/flutter_local_notifications_platform_linux.dart:18:5:
Error: Type 'SelectNotificationCallback' not found.
    SelectNotificationCallback? onSelectNotification,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart:116:5: Error:
'SelectNotificationCallback' isn't a type.
    SelectNotificationCallback? onSelectNotification,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart:177:45: Error: Too
many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 2 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
          const NotificationAppLaunchDetails(false, null);
                                            ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface-6.0.0/lib/src/types.dart:111:9: Context: Found this candidate,
but the arguments don't match.
  const NotificationAppLaunchDetails(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:51:39: Error: Too
many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 2 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
        ? NotificationAppLaunchDetails(result['notificationLaunchedApp'],
                                      ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface-6.0.0/lib/src/types.dart:111:9: Context: Found this candidate,
but the arguments don't match.
  const NotificationAppLaunchDetails(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:99:3: Error:
'SelectNotificationCallback' isn't a type.
  SelectNotificationCallback? _onSelectNotification;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:110:5: Error:
'SelectNotificationCallback' isn't a type.
    SelectNotificationCallback? onSelectNotification,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:472:3: Error:
'SelectNotificationCallback' isn't a type.
  SelectNotificationCallback? _onSelectNotification;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:494:5: Error:
'SelectNotificationCallback' isn't a type.
    SelectNotificationCallback? onSelectNotification,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:702:3: Error:
'SelectNotificationCallback' isn't a type.
  SelectNotificationCallback? _onSelectNotification;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-10.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:725:5: Error:
'SelectNotificationCallback' isn't a type.
    SelectNotificationCallback? onSelectNotification,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/view/base/main_app_bar.dart:33:13: Error: 'MenuBar' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/menu_anchor.dart' and
'package:flutter_grocery/view/base/menu_bar.dart'.
            MenuBar(),
            ^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications_linux-0.3.1-dev.1/lib/src/flutter_local_notifications_stub.dart:26:5: Error:
'SelectNotificationCallback' isn't a type.
    SelectNotificationCallback? onSelectNotification,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications_linux-0.3.1-dev.1/lib/src/flutter_local_notifications_platform_linux.dart:18:5:
Error: 'SelectNotificationCallback' isn't a type.
    SelectNotificationCallback? onSelectNotification,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             50.9s
Failed to compile application.
PS C:\Users\NONIBD\AndroidStudioProjects\User app and web>
```

here is my app\build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.jazzbazar.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

here is my android\build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.jazzbazar.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

here is pubspec.yml

```
name: flutter_grocery
description: A new Flutter application.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.1.0+2

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  provider: ^6.0.2
  http: ^0.13.1
  freezed: ^2.0.3+1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  dio: ^4.0.4
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+8
  pin_code_fields: ^7.0.0
  google_maps_flutter_web: ^0.4.0+3
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.3
  flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
  geocoding: ^2.0.0
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  shimmer_animation: ^2.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.2
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.2.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^10.0.0-dev.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  flutter_html: ^2.2.1
  connectivity: ^3.0.2
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0-nullsafety.0
  fluro: ^2.0.3
  url_strategy: ^0.2.0
  universal_html: ^2.0.8
  universal_ui: ^0.0.8
  flutter_widget_from_html_core: ^0.9.0
  phone_number: ^1.0.0
  country_code_picker: ^2.0.2
  flutter_typeahead: ^4.0.0
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.4.3+7
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/image/
    - assets/language/

  fonts:
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/font/Poppins-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/font/Poppins-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/font/Poppins-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/font/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/font/Poppins-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

i want to solve this issue. i already run my business. but now i'm unable to build web and apk.

Comment: Did you upgrade from `flutter_local_notification` version 9 to version 10? (I see version 10 is throwing errors in the logs you posted). In version 10 a bunch of [breaking changes](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/changelog#:~:text=%5B10.0.0%5D-,Breaking%20change,-%5BAndroid%5D%20zonedSchedule) were introduced.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).